# Load & unload shell extension library

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, shell-extensions

I am developing a context menu (shell extension), and when I try to rebuild the solution it says that the .dll library cannot be opened because it is in use. How can I unload the library manually so I can rebuild it and load it again after rebuilt? Any cmd line commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here are some tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on working with shell extensions.  You can either manually shutdown and restart the shell between sessions, or you can configure the shell to unload your extension quicker.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I found:
There is a small free program called [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) with which I disable the shell extension, I restart the explorer using the command: *taskkill /f /im explorer.exe*, rebuild the library in visual studio, enable the extension in ShellExView and start explorer again using explorer.exe in command  prompt.

Comment: Simplest solution: Change extension CLSID in registry and restart Exlorer using Task Manager.